# Unable to Access Request URL in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am trying to access the request URL from the "Before Header" in the branches by making use of routines such as `"APEX_PAGE.GET_URL"` and `"APEX_UTIL.HOST_URL"` but I am unable to get the entire URL string.

This is my request URL "https://HOST/f?p=125:2:SESSION:RTF:::P2_ID:1111" which has a parameter along with a value being passed. Now I need to access the string `"f?p=125:2:SESSION:RTF:::P2_ID:1111" from "Before Header"` in the branches. Can you please share your thoughts.

Comment: I am using apex 5.1.3 version

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: If the user decides to download the data of the report by making a request like "https://HOST/f?p=125:2:SESSION:RTF:::P2_ID:1111". 

I need to implement some PL/SQL validations on the user and the ID "1111" to check some business conditions before I allow the user to download the data pertaining to ID "1111"

Comment: These sound like conditions that should be in the relevant query, or condition on the report, using :APP_USER as a reference, and :P2_ID as the bind variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will have a try by placing the condition on the report. Just out of curiosity, does it mean that we can't access the URL string anywhere in the code ?

Comment: You can get parts of the URL in javascript, e.g. `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: But usually you don't need to - information within the url is available through other means.